# what is difference between IIF and DECODE in informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

What is difference between **IIF** and DECODE functions in **informatica** power center.

Answer (score 0):

`Decode` can be used in `Select` statement whereas `IIF` cannot be used in a `Select` statement.

Comment: Can you be specific and help me with an example.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I knew Decode will stop looking further if I finds the first match and IIF will complete the search till the end

Also you can use Decode in select clause

Answer (score 0):

First of all DECODE gives you much cleaner code than nested IIFs. In addition, it's more efficient in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Decode**

Finds the column value and generates the result according to the expression

```html
Syntax: DECODE (Column_name or ‘Value’, Search1, Result1, Search2, Result2, ….., Default)
 
Argument               Mandatory/Optional Description
Column_name or Value   Mandatory Value that is to be passed to the function
Search Mandatory       Argument that is to be searched 
Result Mandatory       Result for the search value
Default Optional       Default value in case of search does not 

Example1: DECODE (ID, 1, ‘US
3, ‘Australia’, ‘None’)
Input Data: ID  Value 
            1     US
            2     UK
            3     Australia
            4 
                    Africa

Output Data: ID  Value 
                1     US
                2     None
                3     Australia
                4     None
                None
```

**

Finds the column value and generates the result according to the expression